# ES6 fail-soft destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

On the Babel website, I found the following demo in the scope of destructuring:

```
// Fail-soft destructuring
var [a] = [];
a === undefined;
```

After transpiling this piece of code with Babel, I get the following result in ES5:

```
"use strict";

var _ref = [];
var a = _ref[0];
```

What is fail-soft destructuring used for, and what is the logic behind the transpiled syntax? Edit: why does Babel transpile the ES6 code this way, rather than just assigning `undefined` to the variable?

Edit: 
I see, I guess it just puts the variable value to `undefined`instead of throwing an error. Still some doubt about the transpilation logic though.

Comment: Why should the content of the array influence the transpilation?

Comment: @zeroflagL No reason at all, I was going in a totally wrong direction in my mind, thinking that there was something complex / special about this soft-destructuring thingy and forgetting that we were just assigning an array - hum. Didn't see it was just this simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what happens when you add some more to the example:

```
var [a, b, c] = [];
```

Transpiles to:

```
"use strict";

var _ref = [];
var a = _ref[0];
var b = _ref[1];
var c = _ref[2];
```

`a` gets the first thing, `b` the second, etc.

Comment: Perhaps I formulated my question. My actual question is why Babel performs the transpilation this way. I'll rephrase.

Comment: Updated to correct answer... I was thinking in objects the first time, not arrays.

Comment: Of course so obvious, not sure why I didn't see that. Thanks :-)